# Failure calling API with CFHTTP

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm trying to pass some XML with `cfhttp` as follows to an API :

```
<cfxml variable="elementvalue">
    <entry name='DENY_TEST'>
        <to>
            <member>Public</member>
        </to>
        <from>
            <member>VPN_CLIENTS</member>
        </from>
        <source>
            <member>any</member>
        </source>
        <destination>
            <member>any</member>
        </destination>
        <source-user>
            <member>any</member>
        </source-user>
        <category>
            <member>any</member>
        </category>
        <application>
            <member>bittorrent</member>
            <member>skype</member>
        </application>
        <service>
            <member>application-default</member>
        </service>
        <hip-profiles>
            <member>any</member>
        </hip-profiles>
        <action>deny</action>
        <rule-type>universal</rule-type>
        <disabled>no</disabled>
    </entry>
</cfxml>
```

This is the `cfhttp` call that I attempted:

```
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://domain.com/api" result="objGet" throwonerror="Yes"> 
    <cfhttpparam name="type" type="formfield" value="config" /> 
    <cfhttpparam name="action" type="formfield" value="set" /> 
    <cfhttpparam name="key" type="formfield" value="LUZReHB3TVlyYrODNENGVpRmYvVmEvWW5uVjBzZHo4cz0=" /> 
    <cfhttpparam name="xpath" type="formfield" value="/config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/vsys/entry[@name='vsys1']/rulebase/security/rules" />
    <cfhttpparam name="element" type="formfield" value="#elementvalue#" />
</cfhttp>
```

If I use this in a browser everything works fine and I get success.

```
https://domain.com/api/?type=config&action=set&key=LUZReHB3TVlyYrODNENGVpRmYvVmEvWW5uVjBzZHo4cz0=&xpath==/config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/vsys/entry[@name='vsys1']/rulebase/security/rules&element=<entry name="DENY_TEST"><to><member>Public</member></to><from><member>VPN_CLIENTS</member></from><source><member>any</member></source><destination><member>any</member></destination><source-user><member>any</member></source-user><category><member>any</member></category><application><member>bittorrent</member><member>skype</member></application><service><member>application-default</member></service><hip-profiles><member>any</member></hip-profiles><action>deny</action><rule-type>universal</rule-type><disabled>no</disabled></entry>
```

Any idea why this could be failing? It is stopping at element.  Am I right in using `cfxml` for this or should I try using a variable with backslashes?

Comment: I also tried type="xml" instead of formfield but I'm told I can't mix formfields and xml types in the same cfhttp.  I used a normal variable and saved contents as a string but got the same error even if I backslash the <>.

Comment: In a browser you end up with url variables suggesting that the form has method = "get" in the form tag.  Maybe type = "url" in your cfhttpparam tags would do the trick.

Comment: I did use get too, thanks for this

Comment: Have you tried working with the encoded="true/false" attribute for cfhttpparam?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the ssl certificate on the device.  It didn't occur to me to test it with http first.  To use ssl I had to import the device's certificate in CF's keystore.   I also used the following to store xml in a variable:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="elementvalue"><entry name='DENY_TEST'>
<to>
<member>Public</member>
</to>
<from>
<member>VPN_CLIENTS</member>
</from>
<source>
<member>any</member>
</source>
<destination>
<member>any</member>
</destination>
<source-user>
<member>any</member>
</source-user>
<category>
<member>any</member>
</category>
<application>
<member>bittorrent</member>
<member>skype</member>
</application>
<service>
<member>application-default</member>
</service>
<hip-profiles>
<member>any</member>
</hip-profiles>
<action>deny</action>
<rule-type>universal</rule-type>
<disabled>no</disabled>
</entry>
</cfsavecontent>
```